# QT: prevent code file names appearing in debug strings in release application

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

I am building an application using QT in visual studio and have found that when i run strings over the Release binary it contains full path names to the source files used to compile it. An example of the strings I am seeing is shown below with the project directory removed.

```
1accept()
C:\Users\Tyler\Documents\<PROJECT_DIRECTORY>\GeneratedFiles\ui_InfoDialog.h:49
2rejected()
C:\Users\Tyler\Documents\<PROJECT_DIRECTORY>\GeneratedFiles\ui_InfoDialog.h:50
```

The lines refer to Connect statements in the code, by the looks of them they appear to be part of some error reporting statues. Does anyone know if there is a way to tell QT to not compile those strings into the program.

Comment: Maybe you just can try to use new signal and slot syntax (https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)?

Comment: Also you can try add `DEFINES += QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT QT_NO_WARNING_OUTPUT` into your `pro` file.